# Command line move all files of certain types with NO overwrite /y NOT WORKING

Tags: windows, cmd

Having problems with cmd prompt command:

```
for /r E:\ %f in (*.jpg) do @move "%f" "E:\jpg" /Y
```

This command line is not working the way I intended it. I'm trying to move all files on my external drive of a certain type (i.e jpg) to a folder ON my external drive(E:/jpg)

Any suggestions???

[1. (with /Y)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RJxB.png)

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.125]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\█████>for /r E:\ %f in (*.jpg) do @move "%f" "E:\jpg" /Y
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

[2. (without /Y)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwLZy.png)

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.125]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\█████>for /r E:\ %f in (*.jpg) do @move "%f" "E:\jpg"
Overwrite E:\jpg\10255420_10200945699085042_5035519864603771578_n.jpg? (Yes/No/All): Yes
        1 file(s) moved.
Overwrite E:\jpg\10307411_10201163984180409_2977646430196181302_n.jpg? (Yes/No/All):
```

Comment: If you remove the `@` you will see the command executing.

Comment: read the output of `move /?` and correct the syntax.(note the position of the swich)

Comment: You also need to ensure that each copied `.jpg` file placed in `E:\jpg` isn't picked back up by `(*.jpg)` and `Overwrite` `move`d over itself, creating an unending cycle. I notice that you're `move`ing files from `$RECYCLE.BIN`s; to be safer, I'd suggest that `cmd.exe` is `Run as administrator`.

Answer (score 0):

For moving files you can use robocopy instead of move, by default it does not overwrite files at the destination unless they have different sizes or timestamps, and handles multiple files.

You should be able to one line it with

`robocopy %cd% "E:\jpg" *.jpg /MOV`

note: `cd` is the environment variable for the current directory

see https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html